# Java Project to Spring Restful services

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am very new to Spring and REST. I've practiced few tutorials on Spring from internet and successfully executed few projects.

Now I have a plain Java project (with 5 packages 12 classes). I would like to convert this Java project to Spring framework with REST Services. I have nearly 4 (out of 12)  classes (which would be my services). (I don't have any UI).

Can someone please help me out on how to convert this project to Spring-REST? I've been searching all over internet but nothing matches my context.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: As is this is way too broad, you should ask for something more specific than "Can someone please help me out on how to convert this project to Spring-REST"

Comment: Google: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: @RC. In some sense, you are right, because there are many ways to do that. On the other hand: Spring Boot is today *the* starting place. And that's most probably, what the OP was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for that Grady

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way to go IMHO is via [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) Spring Boot makes it easily to bootstrap a fully working Spring-REST-Stack. In combination with [Spring Tool Suite](https://spring.io/tools), you are [up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8AdyMlpmPk) in no time.